# Terraform error "This object does not have an attribute named "id"" on azurerm_policy_definition

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I have Policy definition module with this main:

[main.tf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EidRG.png)

And I want to create an ountput variable with this settings:

[output.tf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmYPG.png)

But i got an error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkXI3.png)

By the [Terraform Documation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.40.0/docs/resources/policy_definition)
this resource should accept id.

thanks!
Or

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are trying to get the id value from a list of resources. See if the following works:

```
output "policy_definition_output_id" {
    value = ”[${azurerm_policy_definition.policy_definition.*.id}]"
}
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: With the exact same error message?

Comment: Yes, the same error